# Change color of items in appbar

Tags: android

I want to change the color of my app name, search icon and overflow menu in the appbar to white. I used textColorPrimary but its not working, it is all black.

Here is my code

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#9C27B0</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#CE93D8</color>
    <color name="textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="windowBackground">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="navigationBarColor">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF80AB</color>
</resource>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
     <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome">
    </activity>
```

**menumain.xml**

```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    </menu>
```

This is what I want - A white text(app name), search icon(fixed,i used a white search icon so no problem) and white overflow menu

[image: This is what I want]

Comment: check this-http://blog.mohitkanwal.com/blog/2015/03/07/styling-material-toolbar-in-android/

Comment: @KeyurThumar Thanks but am not applying any effect or styling at all, just want to change the color of app name and items in toolbar to WHITE.

Comment: for that you have to either apply style theme or you have to make it custom toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Below theme will work

```
 <style name="ToolbarThemeWhite" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Use like

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        ...
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarThemeWhite"
       ...
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create this style and set to `Toolbar`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- Customize color of navigation drawer icon and back arrow --> 
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <!-- Set proper title size -->
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar</item>
    <!-- Set title color -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Toolbar code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/toolbar_bg"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in your style:

```
 <style name="TextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This only made the text in the overflow menu to be white, the app name, and the overflow menu in the app bar is still black.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED...Strangely it was rendering with black but when I run on a real device it was white.!!